# Why is esbuild not installed when creating new Rails 7 app with Bootstrap?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-5, ruby-on-rails-7, esbuild

I create a new Rails 7 app using the following syntax in the command line:

`$ rails new app_name --css=bootstrap`

I get the following errors when the app is being created (only when including `--css=bootstrap`):

```
Install esbuild
         run  yarn add esbuild from "."
yarn add v1.23.0-20220130.1630
info No lockfile found.
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
info esbuild-darwin-64@0.14.43: The CPU architecture "arm64" is incompatible with this module.
info "esbuild-darwin-64@0.14.43" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info esbuild-android-64@0.14.43: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "esbuild-android-64@0.14.43" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info esbuild-android-64@0.14.43: The CPU architecture "arm64" is incompatible with this module.
info esbuild-linux-arm64@0.14.43: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "esbuild-linux-arm64@0.14.43" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info esbuild-freebsd-64@0.14.43: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "esbuild-freebsd-64@0.14.43" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info esbuild-freebsd-64@0.14.43: The CPU architecture "arm64" is incompatible with this module.
info esbuild-linux-32@0.14.43: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "esbuild-linux-32@0.14.43" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info esbuild-linux-32@0.14.43: The CPU architecture "arm64" is incompatible with this module.
info esbuild-linux-arm@0.14.43: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "esbuild-linux-arm@0.14.43" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info esbuild-linux-arm@0.14.43: The CPU architecture "arm64" is incompatible with this module.
info esbuild-linux-ppc64le@0.14.43: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "esbuild-linux-ppc64le@0.14.43" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info esbuild-linux-ppc64le@0.14.43: The CPU architecture "arm64" is incompatible with this module.
info esbuild-linux-mips64le@0.14.43: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "esbuild-linux-mips64le@0.14.43" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info esbuild-linux-mips64le@0.14.43: The CPU architecture "arm64" is incompatible with this module.
info esbuild-linux-s390x@0.14.43: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "esbuild-linux-s390x@0.14.43" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info esbuild-linux-s390x@0.14.43: The CPU architecture "arm64" is incompatible with this module.
info esbuild-netbsd-64@0.14.43: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "esbuild-netbsd-64@0.14.43" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info esbuild-netbsd-64@0.14.43: The CPU architecture "arm64" is incompatible with this module.
info esbuild-linux-riscv64@0.14.43: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "esbuild-linux-riscv64@0.14.43" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info esbuild-linux-riscv64@0.14.43: The CPU architecture "arm64" is incompatible with this module.
info esbuild-sunos-64@0.14.43: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "esbuild-sunos-64@0.14.43" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info esbuild-sunos-64@0.14.43: The CPU architecture "arm64" is incompatible with this module.
info esbuild-windows-32@0.14.43: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "esbuild-windows-32@0.14.43" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info esbuild-windows-32@0.14.43: The CPU architecture "arm64" is incompatible with this module.
info esbuild-openbsd-64@0.14.43: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "esbuild-openbsd-64@0.14.43" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info esbuild-openbsd-64@0.14.43: The CPU architecture "arm64" is incompatible with this module.
info esbuild-windows-arm64@0.14.43: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "esbuild-windows-arm64@0.14.43" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info esbuild-android-arm64@0.14.43: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "esbuild-android-arm64@0.14.43" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info esbuild-windows-64@0.14.43: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "esbuild-windows-64@0.14.43" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info esbuild-windows-64@0.14.43: The CPU architecture "arm64" is incompatible with this module.
info esbuild-freebsd-arm64@0.14.43: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "esbuild-freebsd-arm64@0.14.43" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info esbuild-linux-64@0.14.43: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "esbuild-linux-64@0.14.43" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info esbuild-linux-64@0.14.43: The CPU architecture "arm64" is incompatible with this module.
[3/4]   Linking dependencies...
[4/4]   Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
success Saved 2 new dependencies.
info Direct dependencies
└─ esbuild@0.14.43
info All dependencies
├─ esbuild-darwin-arm64@0.14.43
└─ esbuild@0.14.43
✨  Done in 1.56s.
Add build script
         run  npm set-script build "esbuild app/javascript/*.* --bundle --sourcemap --outdir=app/assets/builds" from "."
npm WARN set-script set-script is deprecated, use `npm pkg set scripts.scriptname="cmd" instead.
         run  yarn build from "."
yarn run v1.23.0-20220130.1630
$ esbuild app/javascript/*.* --bundle --sourcemap --outdir=app/assets/builds

  app/assets/builds/application.js      55b
  app/assets/builds/application.js.map  93b

✨  Done in 0.29s.
       rails  turbo:install stimulus:install
Import Turbo
      append  app/javascript/application.js
Install Turbo
         run  yarn add @hotwired/turbo-rails from "."
yarn add v1.23.0-20220130.1630
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
info esbuild-android-64@0.14.43: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "esbuild-android-64@0.14.43" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info esbuild-android-64@0.14.43: The CPU architecture "arm64" is incompatible with this module.
info esbuild-android-arm64@0.14.43: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "esbuild-android-arm64@0.14.43" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info esbuild-darwin-64@0.14.43: The CPU architecture "arm64" is incompatible with this module.
info "esbuild-darwin-64@0.14.43" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info esbuild-freebsd-64@0.14.43: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "esbuild-freebsd-64@0.14.43" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info esbuild-freebsd-64@0.14.43: The CPU architecture "arm64" is incompatible with this module.
info esbuild-freebsd-arm64@0.14.43: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "esbuild-freebsd-arm64@0.14.43" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info esbuild-linux-32@0.14.43: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "esbuild-linux-32@0.14.43" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info esbuild-linux-32@0.14.43: The CPU architecture "arm64" is incompatible with this module.
info esbuild-linux-64@0.14.43: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "esbuild-linux-64@0.14.43" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info esbuild-linux-64@0.14.43: The CPU architecture "arm64" is incompatible with this module.
info esbuild-linux-arm@0.14.43: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "esbuild-linux-arm@0.14.43" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info esbuild-linux-arm@0.14.43: The CPU architecture "arm64" is incompatible with this module.
info esbuild-linux-arm64@0.14.43: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "esbuild-linux-arm64@0.14.43" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info esbuild-linux-mips64le@0.14.43: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "esbuild-linux-mips64le@0.14.43" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info esbuild-linux-mips64le@0.14.43: The CPU architecture "arm64" is incompatible with this module.
info esbuild-linux-ppc64le@0.14.43: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "esbuild-linux-ppc64le@0.14.43" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info esbuild-linux-ppc64le@0.14.43: The CPU architecture "arm64" is incompatible with this module.
info esbuild-linux-riscv64@0.14.43: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "esbuild-linux-riscv64@0.14.43" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info esbuild-linux-riscv64@0.14.43: The CPU architecture "arm64" is incompatible with this module.
info esbuild-linux-s390x@0.14.43: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "esbuild-linux-s390x@0.14.43" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info esbuild-linux-s390x@0.14.43: The CPU architecture "arm64" is incompatible with this module.
info esbuild-netbsd-64@0.14.43: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "esbuild-netbsd-64@0.14.43" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info esbuild-netbsd-64@0.14.43: The CPU architecture "arm64" is incompatible with this module.
info esbuild-openbsd-64@0.14.43: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "esbuild-openbsd-64@0.14.43" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info esbuild-openbsd-64@0.14.43: The CPU architecture "arm64" is incompatible with this module.
info esbuild-sunos-64@0.14.43: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "esbuild-sunos-64@0.14.43" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info esbuild-sunos-64@0.14.43: The CPU architecture "arm64" is incompatible with this module.
info esbuild-windows-32@0.14.43: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "esbuild-windows-32@0.14.43" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info esbuild-windows-32@0.14.43: The CPU architecture "arm64" is incompatible with this module.
info esbuild-windows-64@0.14.43: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "esbuild-windows-64@0.14.43" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info esbuild-windows-64@0.14.43: The CPU architecture "arm64" is incompatible with this module.
info esbuild-windows-arm64@0.14.43: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "esbuild-windows-arm64@0.14.43" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4]   Linking dependencies...
[4/4]   Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
success Saved 3 new dependencies.
info Direct dependencies
└─ @hotwired/turbo-rails@7.1.3
info All dependencies
├─ @hotwired/turbo-rails@7.1.3
├─ @hotwired/turbo@7.1.0
└─ @rails/actioncable@7.0.3
✨  Done in 3.62s.
Run turbo:install:redis to switch on Redis and use it in development for turbo streams
Create controllers directory
      create  app/javascript/controllers
      create  app/javascript/controllers/index.js
      create  app/javascript/controllers/application.js
      create  app/javascript/controllers/hello_controller.js
Import Stimulus controllers
      append  app/javascript/application.js
Install Stimulus
         run  yarn add @hotwired/stimulus from "."
yarn add v1.23.0-20220130.1630
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
info esbuild-android-64@0.14.43: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "esbuild-android-64@0.14.43" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info esbuild-android-64@0.14.43: The CPU architecture "arm64" is incompatible with this module.
info esbuild-android-arm64@0.14.43: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "esbuild-android-arm64@0.14.43" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info esbuild-darwin-64@0.14.43: The CPU architecture "arm64" is incompatible with this module.
info "esbuild-darwin-64@0.14.43" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info esbuild-freebsd-64@0.14.43: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "esbuild-freebsd-64@0.14.43" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info esbuild-freebsd-64@0.14.43: The CPU architecture "arm64" is incompatible with this module.
info esbuild-freebsd-arm64@0.14.43: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "esbuild-freebsd-arm64@0.14.43" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info esbuild-linux-32@0.14.43: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "esbuild-linux-32@0.14.43" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info esbuild-linux-32@0.14.43: The CPU architecture "arm64" is incompatible with this module.
info esbuild-linux-64@0.14.43: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "esbuild-linux-64@0.14.43" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info esbuild-linux-64@0.14.43: The CPU architecture "arm64" is incompatible with this module.
info esbuild-linux-arm@0.14.43: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "esbuild-linux-arm@0.14.43" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info esbuild-linux-arm@0.14.43: The CPU architecture "arm64" is incompatible with this module.
info esbuild-linux-arm64@0.14.43: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "esbuild-linux-arm64@0.14.43" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info esbuild-linux-mips64le@0.14.43: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "esbuild-linux-mips64le@0.14.43" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info esbuild-linux-mips64le@0.14.43: The CPU architecture "arm64" is incompatible with this module.
info esbuild-linux-ppc64le@0.14.43: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "esbuild-linux-ppc64le@0.14.43" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info esbuild-linux-ppc64le@0.14.43: The CPU architecture "arm64" is incompatible with this module.
info esbuild-linux-riscv64@0.14.43: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "esbuild-linux-riscv64@0.14.43" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info esbuild-linux-riscv64@0.14.43: The CPU architecture "arm64" is incompatible with this module.
info esbuild-linux-s390x@0.14.43: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "esbuild-linux-s390x@0.14.43" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info esbuild-linux-s390x@0.14.43: The CPU architecture "arm64" is incompatible with this module.
info esbuild-netbsd-64@0.14.43: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "esbuild-netbsd-64@0.14.43" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info esbuild-netbsd-64@0.14.43: The CPU architecture "arm64" is incompatible with this module.
info esbuild-openbsd-64@0.14.43: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "esbuild-openbsd-64@0.14.43" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info esbuild-openbsd-64@0.14.43: The CPU architecture "arm64" is incompatible with this module.
info esbuild-sunos-64@0.14.43: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "esbuild-sunos-64@0.14.43" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info esbuild-sunos-64@0.14.43: The CPU architecture "arm64" is incompatible with this module.
info esbuild-windows-32@0.14.43: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "esbuild-windows-32@0.14.43" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info esbuild-windows-32@0.14.43: The CPU architecture "arm64" is incompatible with this module.
info esbuild-windows-64@0.14.43: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "esbuild-windows-64@0.14.43" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info esbuild-windows-64@0.14.43: The CPU architecture "arm64" is incompatible with this module.
info esbuild-windows-arm64@0.14.43: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "esbuild-windows-arm64@0.14.43" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4]   Linking dependencies...
[4/4]   Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
success Saved 1 new dependency.
info Direct dependencies
└─ @hotwired/stimulus@3.0.1
info All dependencies
└─ @hotwired/stimulus@3.0.1
✨  Done in 1.34s.
       rails  css:install:bootstrap
Build into app/assets/builds
       exist  app/assets/builds
   identical  app/assets/builds/.keep
File unchanged! The supplied flag value not found!  app/assets/config/manifest.js
Stop linking stylesheets automatically
        gsub  app/assets/config/manifest.js
File unchanged! The supplied flag value not found!  .gitignore
File unchanged! The supplied flag value not found!  .gitignore
Remove app/assets/stylesheets/application.css so build output can take over
      remove  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
Add stylesheet link tag in application layout
File unchanged! The supplied flag value not found!  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
      append  Procfile.dev
Add bin/dev to start foreman
   identical  bin/dev
Install Bootstrap with Bootstrap Icons and Popperjs/core
      create  app/assets/stylesheets/application.bootstrap.scss
         run  yarn add sass bootstrap bootstrap-icons @popperjs/core from "."
yarn add v1.23.0-20220130.1630
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
info esbuild-android-64@0.14.43: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "esbuild-android-64@0.14.43" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info esbuild-android-64@0.14.43: The CPU architecture "arm64" is incompatible with this module.
info esbuild-android-arm64@0.14.43: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "esbuild-android-arm64@0.14.43" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info esbuild-darwin-64@0.14.43: The CPU architecture "arm64" is incompatible with this module.
info "esbuild-darwin-64@0.14.43" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info esbuild-freebsd-64@0.14.43: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "esbuild-freebsd-64@0.14.43" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info esbuild-freebsd-64@0.14.43: The CPU architecture "arm64" is incompatible with this module.
info esbuild-freebsd-arm64@0.14.43: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "esbuild-freebsd-arm64@0.14.43" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info esbuild-linux-32@0.14.43: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "esbuild-linux-32@0.14.43" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info esbuild-linux-32@0.14.43: The CPU architecture "arm64" is incompatible with this module.
info esbuild-linux-64@0.14.43: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "esbuild-linux-64@0.14.43" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info esbuild-linux-64@0.14.43: The CPU architecture "arm64" is incompatible with this module.
info esbuild-linux-arm@0.14.43: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "esbuild-linux-arm@0.14.43" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info esbuild-linux-arm@0.14.43: The CPU architecture "arm64" is incompatible with this module.
info esbuild-linux-arm64@0.14.43: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "esbuild-linux-arm64@0.14.43" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info esbuild-linux-mips64le@0.14.43: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "esbuild-linux-mips64le@0.14.43" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info esbuild-linux-mips64le@0.14.43: The CPU architecture "arm64" is incompatible with this module.
info esbuild-linux-ppc64le@0.14.43: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "esbuild-linux-ppc64le@0.14.43" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info esbuild-linux-ppc64le@0.14.43: The CPU architecture "arm64" is incompatible with this module.
info esbuild-linux-riscv64@0.14.43: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "esbuild-linux-riscv64@0.14.43" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info esbuild-linux-riscv64@0.14.43: The CPU architecture "arm64" is incompatible with this module.
info esbuild-linux-s390x@0.14.43: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "esbuild-linux-s390x@0.14.43" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info esbuild-linux-s390x@0.14.43: The CPU architecture "arm64" is incompatible with this module.
info esbuild-netbsd-64@0.14.43: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "esbuild-netbsd-64@0.14.43" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info esbuild-netbsd-64@0.14.43: The CPU architecture "arm64" is incompatible with this module.
info esbuild-openbsd-64@0.14.43: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "esbuild-openbsd-64@0.14.43" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info esbuild-openbsd-64@0.14.43: The CPU architecture "arm64" is incompatible with this module.
info esbuild-sunos-64@0.14.43: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "esbuild-sunos-64@0.14.43" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info esbuild-sunos-64@0.14.43: The CPU architecture "arm64" is incompatible with this module.
info esbuild-windows-32@0.14.43: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "esbuild-windows-32@0.14.43" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info esbuild-windows-32@0.14.43: The CPU architecture "arm64" is incompatible with this module.
info esbuild-windows-64@0.14.43: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "esbuild-windows-64@0.14.43" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info esbuild-windows-64@0.14.43: The CPU architecture "arm64" is incompatible with this module.
info esbuild-windows-arm64@0.14.43: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "esbuild-windows-arm64@0.14.43" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4]   Linking dependencies...
[4/4]   Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
success Saved 21 new dependencies.
info Direct dependencies
├─ @popperjs/core@2.11.5
├─ bootstrap-icons@1.8.3
├─ bootstrap@5.1.3
└─ sass@1.52.3
info All dependencies
├─ @popperjs/core@2.11.5
├─ anymatch@3.1.2
├─ binary-extensions@2.2.0
├─ bootstrap-icons@1.8.3
├─ bootstrap@5.1.3
├─ braces@3.0.2
├─ chokidar@3.5.3
├─ fill-range@7.0.1
├─ fsevents@2.3.2
├─ glob-parent@5.1.2
├─ immutable@4.1.0
├─ is-binary-path@2.1.0
├─ is-extglob@2.1.1
├─ is-glob@4.0.3
├─ is-number@7.0.0
├─ normalize-path@3.0.0
├─ picomatch@2.3.1
├─ readdirp@3.6.0
├─ sass@1.52.3
├─ source-map-js@1.0.2
└─ to-regex-range@5.0.1
✨  Done in 1.60s.
      insert  config/initializers/assets.rb
Appending Bootstrap JavaScript import to default entry point
      append  app/javascript/application.js
Add build:css script
         run  npm set-script build:css "sass ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.bootstrap.scss ./app/assets/builds/application.css --no-source-map --load-path=node_modules" from "."
npm WARN set-script set-script is deprecated, use `npm pkg set scripts.scriptname="cmd" instead.
         run  yarn build:css from "."
yarn run v1.23.0-20220130.1630
$ sass ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.bootstrap.scss ./app/assets/builds/application.css --no-source-map --load-path=node_modules
✨  Done in 1.25s.
```

I'm using an apple M1 machine.

When I try to use bootstrap classes in the app, the button and text styling seems to work as expected, but navbar styling isn't applied.

My questions are:

1. Are these esbuild installation errors the reason why bootstrap isn't working correctly?
2. How do I get esbuild to be installed when I create a new rails 7 app with bootstrap?

Gemfile that gets created:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby "3.1.2"

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem "rails", github: "rails/rails", branch: "main"
gem "rails", "~> 7.0.3"

# The original asset pipeline for Rails [https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails]
gem "sprockets-rails"

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem "sqlite3", "~> 1.4"

# Use the Puma web server [https://github.com/puma/puma]
gem "puma", "~> 5.0"

# Bundle and transpile JavaScript [https://github.com/rails/jsbundling-rails]
gem "jsbundling-rails"

# Hotwire's SPA-like page accelerator [https://turbo.hotwired.dev]
gem "turbo-rails"

# Hotwire's modest JavaScript framework [https://stimulus.hotwired.dev]
gem "stimulus-rails"

# Bundle and process CSS [https://github.com/rails/cssbundling-rails]
gem "cssbundling-rails"

# Build JSON APIs with ease [https://github.com/rails/jbuilder]
gem "jbuilder"

# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem "redis", "~> 4.0"

# Use Kredis to get higher-level data types in Redis [https://github.com/rails/kredis]
# gem "kredis"

# Use Active Model has_secure_password [https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_model_basics.html#securepassword]
# gem "bcrypt", "~> 3.1.7"

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem "tzinfo-data", platforms: %i[ mingw mswin x64_mingw jruby ]

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem "bootsnap", require: false

# Use Sass to process CSS
# gem "sassc-rails"

# Use Active Storage variants [https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#transforming-images]
# gem "image_processing", "~> 1.2"

group :development, :test do
  # See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#debugging-with-the-debug-gem
  gem "debug", platforms: %i[ mri mingw x64_mingw ]
end

group :development do
  # Use console on exceptions pages [https://github.com/rails/web-console]
  gem "web-console"

  # Add speed badges [https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler]
  # gem "rack-mini-profiler"

  # Speed up commands on slow machines / big apps [https://github.com/rails/spring]
  # gem "spring"
end

group :test do
  # Use system testing [https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#system-testing]
  gem "capybara"
  gem "selenium-webdriver"
  gem "webdrivers"
end
```

Comment: Can you list the contents of your gemfile? It looks like it is trying to use esbuild, but that gem is not installed by default in rails 7, instead it would be importmaps to handle the JS. Also, wondering if css-bundling gem is present.

Comment: Added gemfile contents. This is the gemfile that gets created AFTER I run `rails new app_name --css=bootstrap`.

Comment: I found some more clues here https://github.com/evanw/esbuild/issues/1646 and here https://esbuild.github.io/getting-started/#simultaneous-platforms ... haven't managed to solve my issue yet but wanted add the new leads for whoever is reading, maybe it can help with a solution.

Answer (score 1):

1. install yarn & nodejs
2. yarn add esbuild
3. yarn add sass
4. rails new app_name --css bootstrap -j  esbuild
5. rails s